# How to get rid of pages separation?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, user-interface

I am writing a document in MS Word.
There is no need for pages, since I am not going to print it.
Therefore, the breaks in the middle of the document only annoy me.

I found out that I can double click on spaces between pages, and it looks like this:

[image]

But still, is there a way to remove this line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select `View -> Web layout`, as now you are probably using `View -> Print layout`

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use Draft layout it is in View menu;

or at the bottom, close to the right corner of the window.